# Bulk upload response from a google sheet to a google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

Would love to get some help here on a problem that I am trying to solve -

I am trying to figure out a way to do a bulk upload of responses from a google sheet to a google form without having to go to the form and manually adding the responses. I have checked several videos on youtube but most of them talks about creating a form using app script but nothing about uploading responses.

Appreciate any videos/resources you can share! Thanks!

Comment: Get the prefilled link, change the "viewform" to "formResponse", update the link for each response (hopefully easy for you), append `&submit=Submit` to each URL, use Apps Script [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to "click" each link (a default GET call).

Comment: It depends a lot of the structure of the form. The documentation for forms is best. Do you know how to use Apps Script? [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

1. [createResponse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createresponse)
2. [submit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#submit)

---

If it is difficult for you.

1. Generate prefilled url with the values with `CONCATENATE` formula
2. Access and submit